# How to skip text at the beginning of a json file in python

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have a json object file and at the beginning of this file a header of text, date, time, IP address.

I've tried f.readlines()[5:] to no avail.
I've tried next(f)

I wish to skip 5 or 6 lines of text and go directly into the json data.

Here is an example.

```
import jsonlines
import json

data_file = input("Enter a file to parse: ")
with jsonlines.open(data_file) as file:
    for obj in file:
        try:
            jsonparse = json.loads(obj)
        except Exception as e:
            pass
        print(obj)
```

Error:

```
jsonlines.jsonlines.InvalidLineError: line contains invalid json: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) (line 1)
```

Top of json file: 
Start:  07/02/2019 14:59:40.686

Connected To:
192.168.11.203

Here is the full long error:

```
Enter a file to parse: Play.raw
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sdickey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\jsonlines\jsonlines.py", line 159, in read
    value = self._loads(line)
  File "C:\Users\sdickey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\sdickey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\sdickey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sdickey/PycharmProjects/Python Testing/Actall Data/testing.py", line 6, in <module>
    for obj in file:
  File "C:\Users\sdickey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\jsonlines\jsonlines.py", line 204, in iter
    skip_empty=skip_empty)
  File "C:\Users\sdickey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\jsonlines\jsonlines.py", line 164, in read
    six.raise_from(exc, orig_exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
jsonlines.jsonlines.InvalidLineError: line contains invalid json: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) (line 1)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Where are you getting the error? on `jsonlines.open(data_file)`?

Comment: I type my file I wish to parse and stops immediately after. I can run a normal json file without the text at the beginning just fine.

Comment: In your post, you say you get a `jsonlines.jsonlines.InvalidLineError` error. On what line do you get it though?

Comment: Here is the full error:

Comment: You provided no error in that. Could you edit it? thanks.

Comment: Yeah, its to long of an error.

Comment: Then could you put it in the question? You could also use pastebin.

Comment: Why not use `open()` instead `jsonlines.open(data_file)`?

Comment: I've tried that too, to no luck. same error. Also with open()

Comment: it works for me?

Comment: Could you post with what you're using to test with?

Comment: I just changed the `with` statement with `with open(data_file) as file:`

Comment: Jsonlines expects any line passed to it to be valid JSON. You are passing a line that is not JSON, so it is failing. Try using plain "open" and then `f.seek(position_of_first_char_of_JSON)` then pass f into a loop to parse with jsonlines.

Comment: Ok I will try that when I get home thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is always preferable not to read the whole file in memory but one line at a time.

Assuming your input file contains:

```
first line
second line
third line
fourth line
fifth line
{ "k1": "val1", "k2": "val2" }
{ "k3": "val3", "k4": "val4" }
```

if you just want to skip 5 lines, you could do it brutally as:

```
import json

with open("test.txt") as f:
    for _ in range(5):
        next(f)
    for line in f:
        obj = json.loads(line)
        print(obj)
```

or using enumerate:

```
import json

with open("test.txt") as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i<5:
            continue
        obj = json.loads(line)
        print(obj)
```

or use itertools' dropwhile:

```
import itertools as it
import json

with open("test.txt") as f:
    for i, line in it.dropwhile(lambda i: i[0]<5, enumerate(f)):
        obj = json.loads(line)
        print(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to convert to json line by line. You need to join all lines by `\n` igoring the first 5 lines and then load it:

```
import json
with open("test.txt") as f:
  json_obj = "\n".join(f.readlines()[5:])
  jsonparse = json.loads(json_obj)
  print(jsonparse)
```